# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getID' of null

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

The error when trying to load the launcher

```
C:\Development\AlphaLauncher-Recode\app\assets\js\loggerutil.js:29 [Launcher] TypeError: Cannot read property 'getID' of null
    at onDistroLoad (swinger.js:105)
    at swinger.js:71
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85)
```

The Function to set the main id for the Instance manager (ConfigManager).

```
function onDistroLoad(data) {
    if (data != null) {
        if (ConfigManager.getSelectedInstance() == null || data.getInstance(ConfigManager.getSelectedInstance()) == null) {
            loggerLauncher.log('Determining default selected instance..');
            ConfigManager.setSelectedInstance(data.getMainInstance().getID());
            ConfigManager.save();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to load the launcher files via server connection.

```
function initLauncher() {
    setLoadingStatut('Connection loading..');

    DistroManager.pullRemote(ConfigManager.getDistroURL()).then((data) => {
        loggerLauncher.log('Loaded distribution index.');
        onDistroLoad(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
        loggerLauncher.log('Failed to load distribution index.');
        loggerLauncher.error(err);

        setOverlayContent('Can not connect to server!  CRAP!',
            'Please check your internet connection or proxy if you use one..',
            'Close the launcher', null, 15, 'Reconnecting in');
        toggleOverlay(true);
        setCloseHandler(() => {
            closeLauncher();
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            toggleOverlay(false);
            initLauncher();
        }, 15000);
    });
}
```

Sorry for the trouble but I can't seem to get the launcher to connect to the server where the files are stored. The 2.0 version works just fine but the 3.0 (Current Building I'm working on) doesn't want to connect. I may be missing something extremely simple here but I just can't see it.

Comment: From here. data.getMainInstance() is returning just `null` object.

Comment: I know that, I need to know why it's doing that. It might be because of the code I use for the distromanager

Comment: DistroManager.pullRemote seems to resolve with null, so you'll need to dig into that method